# [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table sheets has no column named sheet]

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, express

I added a new column to my Database, but seems like it has not been
added correctly. I am getting the following errors.

This is where I am adding the database

```
const sheets_db = new sqlite3.Database(__dirname + '/sheet.db',
    function(err){
        if(!err){
            sheets_db.run(`
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sheets(
                useremail TEXT,
                sheetname TEXT UNIQUE,
                sheet TEXT,
                status TEXT
                )
            `);
            console.log('opened sheet.db');
        }else{
            console.log('COULD NOT OPEN SHEET.DB', err)
        }
    }

);
```

This is how i am using it

```
sheets_db.run(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO sheets (useremail,sheetname,sheet) VALUES(?,?,?)`,
    ["tim@mun.ca",name,strValues],
    function(err){
        if(!err){
            res.send({ok:true}); //converts to JSON
        }
        else{
            console.log("FAILED TO UPDATE: ",err);
            res.send({ok:false}); //Converts to JSON
        }
    });

});
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
FAILED TO UPDATE:  [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table sheets has no column named sheet] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: Maybe a long shot but since you are using **CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS**, maybe the table already existed before without the field **sheet**? If that's the case, **CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS** won't do anything so the field won't be added. Use this to add a field to an existent table **ALTER TABLE sheets ADD sheet TEXT;**

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I feel you're right, so I deleted the previous database, and rerun the program with new values.

However, now I am getting this error


Could not insert [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: sheets] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}

Comment: Did you execute the **CREATE TABLE** before trying to insert data?

Comment: I had made a mistake. I got it figured out, and you were right about your answer in the beginning. Thanks Gustavo!

Comment: Great! I'm glad to hear it :)